# Does PDO handle sql functions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

Would PDO be able to handle MySQL functions when interfacing a SQL Server (Microsoft)? For example would PDO convert "SELECT MYSQL-FUNCTION(col1) FROM tbl" where in such a use case MYSQL-FUNCTION only exists in SQL Server as SQLSERVER-FUNCTION?

Comment: PDO is an abstraction layer, its not psychic

Comment: Fortunately, I have something like StackOverflow to provide me with knowledge, Dagon. It's the way we learn. Thanks for the feedback, though. :)

Comment: people learnt before S.O and even the internet - think about it ;-)

Comment: A better way to learn is to try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  PDO does not rewrite SQL, not even as much as JDBC does.

As far as I know, only syntax PDO will rewrite is parameter placeholders, for RDBMS brands that don't support named parameters.